# Sql query fills /tmp and takes minutes to run

Tags: mysql

I have a query, which is not operating on a lot of data (IMHO) but takes a number of minutes (5-10) to execute and ends up filling the /tmp space (takes up to 20GB) while executing. Once it's finished the space is freed again.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT c.name, count(b.id), c.parent_accounting_reference, o.contract, a.contact_person, a.address_email, a.address_phone, a.address_fax, concat(ifnull(concat(a.description, ', '),''), ifnull(concat(a.apt_unit, ', '),''), ifnull(concat(a.preamble, ', '),''), ifnull(addr_entered,''))                FROM
                booking b
            join visit v on (b.visit_id = v.id)
            join super_booking s on (v.super_booking_id = s.id)
            join customer c on (s.customer_id = c.id)
            join address a on (a.customer_id = c.id)
            join customer_number cn on (cn.customer_numbers_id = c.id)
            join number n on (cn.number_id = n.id)
            join customer_email ce on (ce.customer_emails_id = c.id)
            join email e on (ce.email_id = e.id)
            left join organization o on (o.accounting_reference = c.parent_accounting_reference)
            left join address_type at on (a.type_id = at.id and at.name_key = 'billing')
            where s.company_id = 1
            and v.expected_start_date between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-02-01 00:00:00'
            group by s.customer_id
            order by count(b.id) desc
```

And the explain plan for the same is:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                | key                 | key_len | ref                                  | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ref    | PRIMARY,FKC4F8739580E01B03,FKC4F8739597AD73B1                | FKC4F8739580E01B03  | 9       | const                                | 74088 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ce    | ref    | FK864C4FFBAF6458E3,customer_emails_id,customer_emails_id_2   | customer_emails_id  | 9       | id_dev.s.customer_id                 |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cn    | ref    | FK530F62CA30E87991,customer_numbers_id,customer_numbers_id_2 | customer_numbers_id | 9       | id_dev.ce.customer_emails_id         |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY             | 8       | id_dev.s.customer_id                 |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY             | 8       | id_dev.ce.email_id                   |     1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | n     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY             | 8       | id_dev.cn.number_id                  |     1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | ref    | PRIMARY,FK6B04D4BEF4FD9A                                     | FK6B04D4BEF4FD9A    | 8       | id_dev.s.id                          |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref    | FK3DB0859E1684683                                            | FK3DB0859E1684683   | 8       | id_dev.v.id                          |     1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ref    | org_acct_reference                                           | org_acct_reference  | 767     | id_dev.c.parent_accounting_reference |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref    | FKADDRCUST,customer_address_idx                              | FKADDRCUST          | 9       | id_dev.c.id                          |   256 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | at    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY             | 8       | id_dev.a.type_id                     |     1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

It appears to be using the correct indexes and such so I can't understand why the large usage of /tmp and long execution time.

Comment: You appear to be misusing a nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. This makes it hard to guess the intent of your query. Read this.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

Your query uses a temporary table, which you can see by the `Using temporary;`  note in the `EXPLAIN` result. Your MySQL settings are probably configured to use /tmp to store temporary tables.

If you want to optimize the query further, you should probably investigate why the temporary table is needed at all. The best way to do that is gradually simplifying the query until you figure out what is causing it. In this case, probably just the amount of rows needed to be processed, so if you really do need all this data, you probably need the temp table too. But don't give up on optimizing on my account ;)

By the way, on another note, you might want to look into COALESCE for handling NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck with a temporary table, because you're doing an aggregate query and then ordering it by one of the results in the aggregate. Your optimizing goal should be to reduce the number of rows and/or columns in that temporary table.

Add an index on `visit.expected_start_date`. This may help MySQL satisfy your query more quickly, especially if your `visit` table has many rows that lie outside the date range in your query.

It looks like you're trying to find the customers with the most bookings in a particular date range.

So, let's start with a subquery to summarize the least amount of material from your database.

```
        SELECT count(*) booking_count, s.customer_id           
          FROM  visit v
          JOIN  super_booking s ON v.super_booking_id = s.id
          JOIN  booking b ON v.id = b.visit_id
         WHERE  v.expected_start_date <= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
           AND  v.expected_start_date >  '2015-02-01 00:00:00'
           AND  s.company_id = 1
         GROUP BY s.customer_id
```

This gives back a list of booking counts and customer ids for the date range and company id in question.  It will be pretty efficient, especially if you put an index on `expected_start_date` in the `visit` table

Then, let's join that subquery to the one that pulls out all that information you need.

```
 SELECT c.name, booking_count, c.parent_accounting_reference, 
        o.contract, 
        a.contact_person, a.address_email, a.address_phone, a.address_fax, 
        concat(ifnull(concat(a.description, ', '),''), 
               ifnull(concat(a.apt_unit, ', '),''), 
               ifnull(concat(a.preamble, ', '),''), 
               ifnull(addr_entered,'')) 
   FROM (
        SELECT count(*) booking_count, s.customer_id           
          FROM  visit v
          JOIN  super_booking s ON v.super_booking_id = s.id
          JOIN  booking b ON v.id = b.visit_id
         WHERE  v.expected_start_date <= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
           AND  v.expected_start_date >  '2015-02-01 00:00:00'
           AND  s.company_id = 1
         GROUP BY s.customer_id 
         ) top
   join customer c on top.customer_id = c.id
   join address a on (a.customer_id = c.id)
   join customer_number cn on (cn.customer_numbers_id = c.id)
   join number n on (cn.number_id = n.id)
        join customer_email ce on (ce.customer_emails_id = c.id)
        join email e on (ce.email_id = e.id)
        left join organization o on (o.accounting_reference = c.parent_accounting_reference)
        left join address_type at on (a.type_id = at.id and at.name_key = 'billing')
  order by booking_count DESC
```

That should speed your work up a whole bunch, by reducing the size of the data you need to summarize.

Note: Beware the trap in `date BETWEEN this AND that`.  You really want

```
     date >= this
 AND date < that
```

because `BETWEEN` means

```
    date >= this
AND date <= that
```